# Browserify: export module and acess via script tag

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

I'm trying to export a javascript module (in this case, with a React implementation) to a file and access it via script tag.

What I've done so far. My script:

```
var Link = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        data: React.PropTypes.object,
        classname: React.PropTypes.string,
        target: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    render: function() {
        return <a href={this.props.data.url} title={ this.props.data.name } className={ this.props.classname }>{ this.props.data.name }</a>;
    }

});

module.exports = Link;
```

Using grunt, I have a task to transpile this to ES5 (using grunt-react) and browserify it:

```
browserify: {
   options: {
     transform: [ require('grunt-react').browserify ]
   },
   client: {
     src: ['src/components/Link.js'],
     dest: 'dist/components/Link.js'
   }
}
```

the Link.js file is generated but the Link variable is not in the window scope.
I don't know if I'm missing something. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Arn't you missing some quotes in your return statement @ Link.render

Comment: @elad.chen no, this is the syntax for React Templates. The grunt-react task compiles it to pure "javascript".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export your `Link` module as `module.exports = Link` it's only available to any component that `require` it. To make that module available in windows scope you have to put it in windows scope like this

```
window.Link = React.createClass({
....
})
```